# Angular evaluating ng-show slowly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a simple verification that evaluates in my controller:

```
<span class="....." ng-show="!ruleHasAnsweredQuestions()">
    Please answer all questions</span>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.ruleHasAnsweredQuestions  = function() { return a+b+c>9; }
```

It's really slow though, taking 1/2 second or so to re-evaluate "a", "b" or "c" changes.

In a general sense, how can I speed up the UI so that once a,b,c changes, the UI is updated faster?

Comment: why not use form validation mechanism and show that once users hit the end of the page ?

Comment: @guilhebl The requirements are for the values to appear dynamically as the form is edited.

Comment: What does the profiler show?  Are you doing a bunch of `$digest()` methods?  How long are they taking?

Comment: Can you tell what is a, b, c, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had added "Animate.css" and the directive 'ngAnimate' to the elements causing a double long animation.

Removing Animate.css fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You can add ng-cloak

```
<span class="....." ng-show="!ruleHasAnsweredQuestions()" ng-cloak>
```

This will prevent the delay.

According to angular js documentation, ng-cloak works by temporarily hiding the marked up element and it does this by essentially applying a style that does this:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. test done in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lGvKKEUlUSuXvA5FXYM8?p=preview):

```
 <span  ng-show="(a+b+c) > 9">
  Please answer all questions
</span>
```